# UITableView Font

Tags: iphone

Im trying to change the font colour on the table view header where it says California / New York. How do i do that?

On a black background the text needs to be white but cant figure this one out.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just don't have that much control over a table's default header styles. Have your table view's delegate return a custom view for each header instead bu implementing -tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:. That view could probably be just a UILabel with the text color set to whatever you like.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to change the header color you can use this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    // create the parent view that will hold header Label
    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)];

    // create the button object
    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.opaque = NO;
    //THE COLOR YOU WANT:
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //THE FONT YOU WANT:
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

    // If you want to align the header text as centered
    // headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);
    //THE TEXT YOU WANT:
    headerLabel.text = <Put here whatever you want to display> // i.e. array element
    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return customView;
}
```